# Can a mechanic's exocortex actually hack?

Tags: class-feature, actions, starfinder, hacking

In Starfinder, a mechanic with an exocortex gains the Wireless Hack ability at 5th level. It allows the exocortex to attempt a Computers check each round against a designated computer within 20 feet, counting as the equivalent of a standard action (Starfinder Core Rulebook pg. 79). Several uses of the Computers skill only require a standard action. However, hacking a computer takes a minimum of a full action (SCR 139). To my knowledge, there are no rules allowing a standard action to substitute for a full action in any way.

Does this mean that an exocortex is unable to hack a system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, it can

The [Wireless Hacking](http://www.starjammersrd.com/classes/mechanic/#Wireless_Hack_Ex_5th_Level) ability says:

> Wireless Hack (Ex) 5th Level
>
> Instead of combat tracking, your exocortex can access another computer system within 20 feet, allowing it to attempt a Computers check against that computer each round, using your skill bonus. **This counts as a standard action for the purpose of the Computers skill**. You must remain within 20 feet of the computer system for the entire time your exocortex is interacting with the computer. If the task requires multiple actions (or even rounds) to accomplish, **you can spend your actions to work in concert with your exocortex, counting both your action and the exocortex’s effective standard action toward the total time required**. If you don’t have the remote hack class feature, you must be adjacent to the computer to attempt your checks.

So, you can combine your actions with your cortex's standard action to finish things faster. That means you can make an attack (standard action) and help your exocortex hack a computer (a move and swift actions), which will help your exocortex to complete the full-round action (standard + move + swift) necessary every round while hacking.

Normally, the time required to hack a computer is based on it's tier. So, if you couldn't split this into multiple actions, it would be impossible for anyone to hack anything but a 1st tier computer.

Not only that, but not *all* uses of the [Computer](http://www.starjammersrd.com/skills/#Computers_Int_Trained_Only) skill will require a full-round action. More specifically:

> DISABLE OR MANIPULATE MODULE
>
> A character with root access to a computer can disable or manipulate a countermeasure or module as a **standard action** with a DC 10 Computers check. If you have access (but not root access) to a computer, you can attempt a Computers check to activate, add, disable, or manipulate any countermeasure or module.

Manipulating a module with a *free* standard action per turn means you could fire a weapon turret, or control a vehicle, or issue commands to a drone, or even send commands to a computer you hacked to shut down cameras, lock/unlock doors, turn off gravity and so on.

Finally, the *Wireless Hack* also improve your **Overload** ability, making it work on devices up to 20 feet away, which enhances the usefulness of the ability.

Comment: Technically, what you're suggesting doesn't allow you to hack any faster. No matter how you slice it, you can't end up with more than one full action per turn. This also leads to another concern. The Coordinated Assault ability (SCR 70) is worded to suggest that helping your exocortex hack requires a check from each participant. It's certainly a boon to be able to take a standard action while hacking, but does this come at the cost of requiring success on two checks for the benefit of one?

Comment: I will clarify on that.

Comment: Could you clarify one more thing, or does this go beyond the scope of the question? As per Coordinated Assault, does using your exocortex to hack by necessity require success on two Computers checks for the benefit of one?

Comment: One more note: based on the wording of Master Control (pg 75) and my understanding of full actions (pg 244), you would need to give up your swift action as well in order to create the full action required to hack.

Comment: Your first question is better as a new question on the site. On the second, I will clarify, but yes, you also use up your swift.